# How to make a Chrome OS app quit itself via Javascript

Tags: google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os

I need to have a chrome app quit based on a js script, but after I've looked through Google's list of [JS APIs for Chrome Apps](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/api_index), I'm not convinced there is a way sadly. I've tried having the program throw errors at itself, but chrome simply ignores them and moves on. By the way, this is for Chrome OS.

Comment: app.window has close() method so maybe something like `chrome.app.window.current().close()`? There's also chrome.app.window.getAll() to close all windows which will make the app quit, effectively.

Comment: close all the windows, and make sure there are no event listeners bound, and then eventually, the event page will go inactive. That's how you "quit"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest hack to make a chrome app "quit" would be to set `chrome.storage.local.set({dont_start:1})` and then `chrome.runtime.reload()` and make sure the `onLaunched` event listener, instead of doing the normal thing like opening an app window, instead checks first if `dont_start` is set, and deletes that key, and just does nothing (instead of launching the app). Then in about 30 seconds or so the event page will go inactive.